# Determine form's identity (type information) at runtime

Tags: c#, casting, runtime

Say I have a common class that performs some time-consuming step (eg. saving stuff to USB). I'd like to be able to call that code from multiple forms and receive feedback whenever a step is completed. How does the common class know to whom to send feedback to? The code below describes the situation:

```
// ### Common class frmCommon ###
// Parent form (when feedback on some slow operation is required)
private static Form m_frmParent = null;

// ...
public static void SetParentForm(Form frmParent)
{
    // When some time consuming process takes place (such as saving to USB), setting the
    // parent form allows feedback to be given to the user (eg. as a progress bar)
    m_frmParent = frmParent;
}

public static void DoSomething()
{
    for (int nStep = 0; nStep < 100; nStep++)
    {
        // Tell the parent form how many product sets (groups of 20) there are to read
        if (m_frmParent != null)
        {
            // How to decide whether to call form 1 or form 2?
            ((frmForm1)m_frmParent).SendFeedback(nStep);
            ((frmForm2)m_frmParent).SendFeedback(nStep);
        }

        // Perform the time-consuming step...
        SlowStep(nStep);
    }
}

// ### FORM 1 frmForm1 ###
private void SomeEventForm1(int nStep)
{
    frmCommon.SetParentForm(this);
    frmCommon.DoSomething();
    frmCommon.SetParentForm(null);
}

public void SendFeedback(int nStep)
{
    // Do something like update a progress bar on form 1
    Application.DoEvents();
}

// ### FORM 2 frmForm2 ###
private void SomeEventForm2(int nStep)
{
    frmCommon.SetParentForm(this);
    frmCommon.DoSomething();
    frmCommon.SetParentForm(null);
}

public void SendFeedback(int nStep)
{
    // Do something like update a progress bar on form 2
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Aiming for .NET 2.0 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Never use `Application.DoEvents();`.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/06/448560.aspx

Comment: Do you really need to select between (frmForm1) and (frmForm2) ?  The SendFeedback is probably a method from `Form`, not from `frmForm1` or `frmForm2` (these two inherit it from `Form`). Then you could do just `m_frmParent.SendFeedback(nStep)`, right?

Comment: @Daniel: Both forms derive from System.Windows.Forms.Form, which doesn't implement a "SendFeedback" method. I suppose I could derive an intermediate base class and let frmForm1 and frmForm2 derive from that class (and implement "SendFeedback" in the base class)...but in the absence of such a common base class?

Comment: The base class would be my suggestion, or better than that, an `Interface`. Or an extension, see my edited answer below.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks, looking into both answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather use an *event*:

```
public class SlowProcess {
  ...
  // Simplest, not thread safe
  public static event EventHandler<int> StepChanged;

  public static void DoSomething() {
    for (int nStep = 0; nStep < 100; nStep++) {
      if (null != StepChanged)
        StepChanged(null, nStep);

      SlowStep(nStep);
    } 
  }
}

...

public partial class MyEventForm: Form {
  ...    
  private void onStepChange(Object sender, int nStep) {
    //TODO: update form here after receiving a feedback 
  }

  private void TraceSlowProcess() {
    // feedback is required 
    SlowProcess.StepChanged += onStepChange;

    try {
      SlowProcess.DoSomething(); 
    }
    finally {
      // No need of feedback
      SlowProcess.StepChanged -= onStepChange;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That works nicely but can you send the integer "nStep" to the event handler in the calling class?

Comment: @AlainD: all you have to do is change `EventHandler` to `EventHandler<int>`, see my edit

Comment: Not sure if EventHandler<int> is supported in .NET 3.0 or higher, but in .NET 2.0 I had to create a custom class "public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs" to handle the event "public static event EventHandler<EventArgs<int>> EventInt;"...and it works nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The calling code will have to provide a delegate to that class.  When the class is done with the time consuming process, it will call that delegate to inform the calling code that it finished.  Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx) for a good tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: Creating and passing a function delegate has proved to be a relatively simple way to solve the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1 - If `SendFeedback` is a function you implemented in both forms, and they do the same, consider creating a single `static` method in a `static class` to **extend** the `Form`:

```
public static class FormExtender
{
    public static void SendFeedback(this Form frm, int nStep)
   {
       //do what must be done
       //you can call this anyhere using, for instance: m_frmParent.SendFeedback(nStep)
       //when you call it like that, m_frmParent will be given to this function as the argument frm
   }

}
```

2 - But if the methods are different in both forms, I suggest you create an interface:

```
interface IFormWithFeedback
{
    void SendFeedback(int nStep);
}
```

Then form1 and form2 should implement this (just add `, IFormWithFeedBack` where your forms are declared):

```
public class frmForm1 : Form, IFormWithFeedback     
public class frmForm2 : Form, IFormWithFeedback
```

And your parent form inside that class should be an `IFormWithFeedback` instead of a form:

```
 private static IFormWithFeedback m_frmParent = null;
```

Both options (extension method or interface) would allow you to call `SendFeedback` direclty from m_frmParent without casting it.